# Activity inside another activity onCreate() method

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to include one activity inside another.

```
<include
    android:id = "@+id/includedactivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/maintabactivity" />
```

I can see all included's activity controls, but onCreate method of maintabactivity is never get called.

Answer (score 2):

```
<include
android:id = "@+id/includedactivity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
layout="@layout/maintabactivity" />
```

only includes the layout in your current layout file in the view rather then it would not call the oncreate method of any other activity.
I think you want to launch another activity to show the new layout.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No, I don't want to hide the current activity and show another. It's hard to explain but I want included activity to work as child. May be I can call this activity's methods somehow?

Comment: instead of creating another activity just create a method in your activity and call that

Comment: This new activity would be created in my app later as normal activity, and I don't want to copy-paste the code, but if there is no other solution...

Comment: then create any static method there access from here

Comment: Ok, how can I get access to the included's layout fields? Edits, Buttons and so on? Thanks